# Can not update value in tool-bar?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

here I added one sample given below

Here if I click add button the "newarray" variable value is updated but it is not reflected. I don't know how to resolve it

> this is the function which is used to add new objects:

```js
export class AppComponent {

  newarray = [
    { text: "Outdent" }
  ];
  public run() {
    this.newarray=[
      { text: "Cut" },
      { text: "Copy" },
      { text: "Paste" },
      { text: "Underline" },
      { text: "Italic" },
      { text: "Color" },
      { text: "Numbering" },
      { text: "Ascending" },
      { text: "Descending" },
      { text: "Indent" },
      { text: "Outdent" },
    ];
  }

}
```

> This is tha sample link [running state sample]:
>   [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f3yr5o?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Did you called `run()` method somewhere?

Comment: nope....!.  please see that sample

Comment: what is your problem ????

Comment: did you see that sample?......In that sample, i declared one array variable[newarray] which has one object. Then when i press add button, the value from anoither array variable[tbararray] values are moved into [newarray] variable but toobar value is not updated.....this is my problem

Answer (score 2):

Your example is changing the `newarray` but your template is iterating over `tbarArray` which is never changed. This is why your view doesn't update.

You can inspect the variables real-time by adding this to your template during development:

```
<pre>newarray: {{ newarray | json }}</pre>
<pre>tbarArray: {{ tbarArray | json }}</pre>
```

this will clear doubt about "is it being updated?" in the future.

Comment: still.... i did not get what you are trying to say?.....please explain clearly .....i am new to this platform

Comment: i changed from [tbararray] to [newarray] in my template but still my view is not updated?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

> Use **ToolbarComponent**

DEMO -----> [Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/syncfusion-ex)

TS:

```
import {
  Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef
} from '@angular/core';

import { ToolbarComponent } from '@syncfusion/ej2-ng-navigations';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('element') el: ToolbarComponent;
  newarray: Array<any>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.newarray = [
      { text: "Cut" },
      { text: "Copy" },
      { text: "Paste" },
      { text: "Underline" },
    ]
  }

  run() {
    let ummy: Array<any> = [
      { text: "Paste" },
      { text: "Underline" },
      { text: "Italic" }]
    this.el.items = ummy
  }
}
```